# Do we know the number of people who converted to Islam in the 23 years of Prophethood of Muhammad?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophets

Salaam everyone.

I have a question. In prophet Mohammad time as a prophet how many converted to Islam.

I did a few Google search but couldn't get any results.

Comment: It's hard to tell since there's no precise numbers about the population of the Arabian peninsula at that time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a number, you will never find it as population count wasn't something kept or census taking at that time. However, if you want to know what kind of land the Prophet converted:

[image]
<sub>(source: [l-spioneers.org](https://moodle.l-spioneers.org/pluginfile.php/15797/mod_book/chapter/18/4851619_orig.gif))</sub>